# Is it possible to determine which cookies are set by a third-party homepage in a php environment?

Tags: php, web-scraping

Is it possible to read the cookies that are sent by a third-party homepage using php? 
In concrete, i want to find out if a page using GTM does also set .ga cookies.

I was thinking of a "virtual browser" solution on the server, is that possible / is anybody experienced with that?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP runs on the server side so it's impossible to know things about the explorer such as screen size, cookies or the position of the mouse in the screen.

Comment: Please clarify the relationship between your PHP, the browser, and "a third-party homepage" here. You can make a simple curl request from PHP to "the third-party homepage" and see what cookies you get back. Is that sufficient? If not, what else are you trying to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

## No, because PHP runs on the server and gets only the cookies of that domain

Cookies are stored on the client (browser). PHP is executed on the other side. The cookies are stored in the browser and the browser sends the cookie values along with the HTTP request to the server.

Therefore, the PHP process only gets to see the cookies of that domain.

And if you think of it, everything else would be a security flaw because every site could read for example secrets of sessions that are open on another site!